# Cheap way to get from Carrasco Airport to Tres Cruces, Montevideo

Tags: airport-transfer, uruguay, montevideo

I'm looking for a cheap way to travel from the Airport of Montevideo/Carrasco to the downtown (city center), more precisely the Barrio of Tres Cruces. Cabs are like 50 €, it's very expensive.

There is a bus *but that they don't let us get in if we carry a travel case*, because the people are often huddled together, therefore there is little space in the bus. Is that true? It would cost between 10-15 €.

I don't care about the duration of the trip. I also looked for some carpooling website but could not find anything

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Carrasco-International-Airport/Tres-Cruces-Montevideo-Montevideo-Department-Uruguay) says Uber is available

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment above, [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Carrasco-International-Airport/Tres-Cruces-Montevideo-Montevideo-Department-Uruguay) offers several options:

- Bus - bag may be a problem, but cheapest of the options
- Taxi- Would work, but more expensive
- Drive - not really an option unless you can hitch
- Uber - middle of the range, and available.

It's up to you as to which of those is more suitable to your purpose/budget.

Answer (score 1):

I went to Montevideo a couple of months ago and found the buses from the airport quite pleasing and not at all as you have heard described - the bus I used to get downtown was not full at all, there were in fact lots of empty seats. I arrived in the afternoon.

It took about an hour to get close to my stop, which is past Tres Cruces - but you said you didn't mind the duration of the trip, so that shouldn't be a problem.

I'd recommend checking [Google Maps's path from the airport to the neighborhood](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Carrasco+International+Airport,+Cap.+Juan+Antonio+Artigas,+Ciudad+de+la+Costa+Canelones,+Uruguai/Tres+Cruces,+Montevid%C3%A9u,+Uruguai/@-34.8432145,-56.1587056,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x959f87e117a691e3:0x223b5948614efdd0!2m2!1d-56.0229841!2d-34.8379636!1m5!1m1!1s0x959f8051b30d290f:0xafa4443090520bbc!2m2!1d-56.1686404!2d-34.8949581!3e3) - this is how I found out which buses I could take; Tres Cruces is close to Centenario Stadium, and as I understood it, several buses from the airport tend to pass through the area (700, 701, 710, etc).